# display javascript array in html table

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, html-table

I am busy with an `HTML` page that I have sent through data from a `database`. I have the array working and I am filtering correctly, then I used a for loop to get the object in an `el` function. the console log's correctly, but the table on the page where I would like to display does a letter on a line.

**`JAVASCRIPT`**

```
function go(){
  var startd = document.getElementById('startdate').value+" 00:00";
  var stopd = document.getElementById('stopdate').value;
  var array = [<%items.forEach(function(item, index){%>{date:"<%= item.Expr1000%>", inout:"<%= item.CHECKTYPE%>", sn:"<%= item.sn%>"},<% });%>{date:"stop"}];
var check = array.filter(function(el){
return el.date >= startd &&
       el.date <= stopd &&
       el.inout &&
       el.sn;

});

check.forEach(function(el){
console.log(el.date);
var table = $('#set');
 var row, cell;
 for(var i=0; i<el.date.length; i++){
 row = $( '<tr />' );
 table.append( row );
 for(var j=0; j<el.date[i].length; j++){
 cell = $('<td>'+el.date[i][j]+'</td>');
 row.append( cell );
 }
 }
});



}
```

Currently displays the **date** like:

```
2
0
1
9
-
0
8
-
1
5

0
7
:
0
0
:
2
1
2
0
1
9
-
0
8
-
1
5

0
7
:
0
0
:
3
0
```

Where I would like to **display** as:

```
 yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
 yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second loop is the problem:

```
for(var j=0; j<el.date[i].length; j++){
  cell = $('<td>'+el.date[i][j]+'</td>');
  row.append( cell );
}
```

That is looping over every character in the date. You don't need the second loop at all—just add the date directly to the `row`:

```
cell = $('<td>'+el.date[i]+'</td>');
row.append( cell );
```

Comment: THANK YOU FOR THAT ONE. It is working now but the table is Duplicating the array object and displays each item 33 time?

Comment: If you an update your question with an example of what the data actually looks like I might be able to help you better.